# How do you set the default website to serve when your IP address is entered as URL?

Tags: apache, ip

I have a server with multiple websites hosted and distinguishable using name-based virtual hosting of apache.

How do I set it so that a specific website is hosted when the ip of my server is entered in the address bar?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I have just upgraded a server to ubuntu 14.04 and the existing 000-default.conf VirtualHost has simply stopped being invoked when no domain name matches – instead the first alphabetical VirtualHost with a ServerName directive is used, for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I just needed to specify a IP address in the default VH, instead of using `*:80` or `_default_:80`. I’m not sure if that’s an apache bug.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you want to use is the `_default_` `VirtualHost`.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/default80
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

It's described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default). Basically if nothing else match the request the `_default_` host will be used.

**EDIT**
This could also be written as:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /www/default
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Is is important that this is the first `VirtualHost` in the configuration since Apache will start matching them from top to bottom, selecting the one that fit the best based on `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`.

This post might also be of interest:
[Apache default VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost)

Comment: I am using debian and I have created the vhost file as you specified in sites-available, there was already a `_default` in there so I modified it and created a new `_default_` with the same configuration...I then linked these files with `ln -s source dest` into sites-enabled...as `a2ensite` said there was no site found matching...it still does not work

Comment: Did you make sure it's the first `VirtualHost` in the config? Meaning it has a name that appear before the other hosts. I think normally you use like `010-default` `020-www` `030-forum` as link names in `site-enabled`.

Comment: If your `apache2.conf` has 0 `VirtualHost` but you `Include sites-enabled/` for all your vhost configs, then, the default site has to appear before the other files. For example, a default vhost file named `aaaa.default` will work but a `zzzz.default` will not work. [Unless `zzzz.default` is your only config]

Comment: In `sites-enabled` there is `_000-default`, `_default` and `_default_`, however going to the server ip goes to the first virtual host after `_default_`

Answer (score 7):

just find the `Include sites-enabled/` line in your `apache2.conf` file and add the path to the conf file you want to be site default above it. from:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

to

```
Include sites-enabled/mydefault.conf
Include sites-enabled/
```

Comment: This is most likely the answer you're looking for, the configs are loaded in alphabetical order, the option I went with was to rename my default config from mysite.conf to 00-mysite.conf (remember to a2dissite a2ensite & reload)

Comment: This is one way. Another is to replace the `000-default.conf` link to point to the file of yours that you want to be loaded first. That way potential updates to the `apache2.conf` file continue to happen when the package gets updated on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it clean, don't delete or edit anything in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

*Create* all new site configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. *Copy* whatever site configuration you want enabled to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Only make sure `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` has only one configuration file.

Sample format for new apache site configurations in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysiteroot/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/mysiteroot>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice that `000-default.conf` is by default in both directories mentioned above and should only be replaced by your new configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` so that it can be restored anytime you need it.

Restart Apache2 service after you make any configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you first install apache2, there is a site configuration file named `000-default.conf`. This is going to be the default because it is very likely to appear first in the list of files under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

To have your own file as the default, you can either replace the file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` with your own, or replace the link like so:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/my-site-setup.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Then restart apache2 (or just reload).

The `_default_` as mentioned by the other answer is for defining a virtual host which can be found with the default IP address. It's not the default virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
...
```

is equivalent to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
```

The `*` is a globing pattern which matches any IP addresses.

Note:

Replacing the `000-default.conf` file is okay, but in most cases the installation package is going to view that as a modified file and manage it in some *weird* way which is why I think it's cleaner to only change the soft link.

Answer (score 0):

Many servers do not have a monolithic configuration file, but several host-specific configuration files for various virtual hosts organized as follows:

/etc/apache2/
sites_available  (actual configuration files)
sites_enabled    (symlinks to files in sites_available)

In order to make a particular virtual host configuration load first when accessed by the shared IP address, rename the symlink (only) to something which will be first when sorted, such as 00-default originally was:

SITES-AVAILABLE EXAMPLES:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Jul 27  2019 00_yourdomain.com.conf -> ../sites-available/yourdomain.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 Jul 27  2019 00_yourdomain.com.ssl.conf -> ../sites-available/yourdomain.com.ssl.conf

*** This is a "clean", easily interpretable, simple method, which (importantly) does not involve the apache2.config file!