# AWS Application ELB Target Group Unhealthy 403?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to figure out why my ELB Target Group is not passing the health check and throwing a 403 (Forbidden) error. Details are:

- AWS Windows 10 Server
- WampServer3 for Apache, PHP, and MySQL
- Application Elastic Load Balancer

I have my ALB Target Group Health Check Setup like so

- Protocol: HTTP
- Path: /folder1/folder2/public/index.php
- Port: traffic port
- Default threshold and timeouts

In my Security Group I have port 80, 443, and 22 open for inbound traffic.

Because it is throwing a 403 (Forbidden) error, I have to assume that the health check "Path" is not setup correctly.

I am using wamp so my default path is **c:/wamp64/www** so naturally I first set up my path to be directed to the homepage of my website (which I am able to access from the web just fine) but the health check still fails and shows the 403 error.

I even tried entering a path that doesn't exist to see if it would throw a different error but it just shows the 403 when hovering over the "i" next to the unhealth tag so I am not even sure the health check is updating.

**Edit**

Ok, after going through the resource that was given below, I have successfully pulled the "**PrivateIP**/index.php" page in cURL.

I have changed my Target Group Health Check Path to "/index.php" but it is still throwing the 403 error.

I am even able to access the homepage of my website publicly from the PrivateIP which seems unsafe but makes me wonder why it is still failing. Below is my setting to allow this in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias xx.xx.xxx.xxx
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/x/x/public/
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/x/x/public/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The server alias is the private IP set by the Elastic IP on my instance.

If anyone has an idea on what to check next please let me know.

Comment: Use curl and test the site via instance IP from the instance. If instance IP is 10.0.0.50, then run curl http://10.0.0.50/folder1/folder2/public/index.php. That is what the ELB is requesting. Check your set up and make sure the site can be referenced as above. If you don't have curl you can use a local browser.

Comment: To keep it simple use /healthcheck.php as the health check target. Make sure that works as above.

Comment: @RodrigoM please see my edit on the question. I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: The ELB health check does not use domain name it uses the instance private IP. Your server is not properly configured to serve the page by its IP. Check apache server configuration.

Comment: Unrelated issue; the `Path: /folder1/folder2/public/index.php` indicate that you're using a framework (like Laravel) that has a public folder, and stuff outside it that shouldn't be public. Your current setup sounds like it would allow people to browse to `/folder1/folder2/.env`

Comment: @RodrigoM Would you be able to send me to a resource that could teach me how to configure the server to serve a private IP?

Comment: @sisve Yes I am using Laravel, the only way someone could navigate to that file is if they were on the server itself. At least I believe that is the way it works. When I am checking the public IP I am doing it on the server, not on my public machine.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost

Comment: @RodrigoM Thank you for that. Please see my edits above. I was able to get the page through cURL but the health check still fails.

Comment: @Matthew have you tried specifying port instead of traffic port while configuring your healthcheck? Also have you tried checking your apache logs to see what ELB is trying to access while doing healthchecks? Logs would point you to the exact location healthcheck is trying to access then you may need to modify some permissions as required.

Comment: @KiranMore Thank you for all your help on this issue, you and RodrigoM have been a tremendous help. I just checked the target status today and it is showing as healthy for port 80. I guess it just took some time to propagate. I am still concerned about setting my Private IP in this way so I will have to see if there is a safer way of doing this. Other than that, now I just need to figure out how to do the same on port 443 so I can force my website to use `https://`. Thank you both so much for your time, I wish I could give rep by up-voting comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this failed health status issue by adding a index.html file on your default wamp path and then check your instance health status in your target group and configure your heath checks in target group just like the below one:

```
Protocol:HTTP
Path:/
Port:80
```

> **File location**: c:/wamp64/www/html/

Comment: For me this was the cause... I was over-expecting that the fact that merely checking for "http://localhost" to be working, would have been sufficient. But No. I had to "touch index.html" on each target server, to get that ALB health-check to pass. Frustrating, but its working now.