# Html5 options for second domain through no-ip.com

Tags: html, apache

I'm using no ip.com and port forwarding through my router to an apache server on a Linux machine.

I have 2 domains with no-ip.com domain A and domain B both to the same public IP. Inside of my HTML folder, my index.html page is for domain A.

What I want to achieve is whenever I navigate to domain A it remains with my original index.html but when I navigate to domain B I would like index2.html or the Apache server to recognize the request is from domain B and direct to index2.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache default VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at configuring [Apache httpd `VirtualHost`s](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).